# How to automate PHP-Flash web application using selenium java

Tags: java, php, flash, selenium, flash-builder

I need to automate a web application which is in PHP with flash. Is it possible to automate the application using selenium java with FlexUISelenium or FlexMonkium.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not modify the php application itself instead of auto-driving it with selenium>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's pure Flash without Flex then you should put some external [like these](http://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/) methods to your Flash application  and call them from your test code in order to verify functionality. If it's Flex then FlexUISelenium and FlexMonkium will help you - but again you should compile these libraries into your Flex app - they contains required methods to be called from Selenium.

In the case you are not allowed to modify your Flash application I would recommend to take a look to image-based tools like [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/)

Comment: Thanks Khrol.. Dev team is not accepting to change the code base and compile them.. So moving to Sikuli.